# Python REGEX matches out of order and substitution of matches from within groups

Tags: python, regex

sample string:

```
base_A23x4_B534x5_C654x6_D2363x45
```

Desired matches:

```
basename=base
A=23.4
B=534.5
C=654.6
D=2363.45
```

This is my regex so far:

```
(?P<basename>\w+)_A(?P<A>[0-9]+x[0-9]+)_B(?P<B>[0-9]+x[0-9]+)_C(?P<C>[0-9]+x[0-9]+)_D(?P<D>[0-9]+x[0-9]+)
```

I have two issues:

1. A,B,C,D,... may appear in any order (and keeps going but only capital letters eg. AA,AZ,AAC)
2. I'd like to replace "x" with "."  Is this possible with regex or do I need to do this separately

Comment: In the future please don't update your question with requirements that significantly differ from your original question. It wastes our time giving answers to your original question that simply don't apply to your updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing groups inside lookaheads to get them in any order. Also note that you should use `\d` rather than `[0-9]`, and that if you want *separate* named capture groups (like `<A>` for the `_A` section, and `<B>` for the `_B` section), you should use separate capture group names rather than repeating `<A>`:

```
(?P<basename>\w+(?=_))(?=.*?_A(?P<A>\d+x\d+))(?=.*?_B(?P<B>\d+x\d+))(?=.*?_C(?P<C>\d+x\d+))(?=.*?_D(?P<D>\d+x\d+))
```

https://regex101.com/r/Ew2uQ2/3

Separated out:

- `(?P<basename>\w+(?=_))` - Match initial `base_` substring
- `(?=.*?_A(?P<A>\d+x\d+))` - Capture closest `A_`
- `(?=.*?_B(?P<B>\d+x\d+))` - Capture closest `B_`
- `(?=.*?_C(?P<C>\d+x\d+))` - Capture closest `C_`
- `(?=.*?_D(?P<D>\d+x\d+))` - Capture closest `D_`

If you don't know the capitalized prefix beforehand and you still want a pure regex solution, you could capture repeated subgroups with the `regex` module:

```
import regex
str = 'base_D2363x45_B534x5_C654x6_A23x4'
match = regex.match(r'(?P<basename>\w+?(?=_))(_[A-Z]+\d+x\d+)+', str)
print(match.captures(2))
```

Output:

```
['_D2363x45', '_B534x5', '_C654x6', '_A23x4']
```

Comment: I had an error in the orig post.  I meant to have separate named capture groups for each group.  Is there a method to auto generate the name based on a match?  I am not limited to 4 groups (A,B,C,D).  I could have 50 groups named with uppercase letters

Comment: It's not possible to automatically generate named capture groups like that, though with the `regex` module, you can get repeated capture groups that you can parse later. (or you can use `findall` on the found `basename` and related substrings, but not sure if that's an option for you)

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookahead patterns:

```
import re
s = 'base_A23x4_B534x5_C654x6_D2363x45'
basename, *numbers = re.match(r'([^_]+)(?=.*(?<=_)A(\d+x\d+))(?=.*(?<=_)B(\d+x\d+))(?=.*(?<=_)C(\d+x\d+))(?=.*(?<=_)D(\d+x\d+))', s).groups()
A, B, C, D = [n.replace('x', '.') for n in numbers]
```

so that `basename`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` will become:

```
base
23.4
534.5
654.6
2363.45
```

and with the value of `A` moved to the end of the string:

```
s = 'base_B534x5_C654x6_D2363x45_A23x4'
```

the result will stay the same.

EDIT: Given your new requirements that there may be any number of alphabet combinations in the string, you should split the string into tokens as convert them to a dict instead:

```
import re
s = 'base_A23x4_B534x5_C654x6_D2363x45_AA12x3'
basename, *tokens = s.split('_')
print({k: v.replace('x', '.') for k, v in dict(re.match(r'([A-Z]+)([\dx]+)', n).groups() for n in tokens).items()})
```

This outputs:

```
{'A': '23.4', 'B': '534.5', 'C': '654.6', 'D': '2363.45', 'AA': '12.3'}
```

Comment: I am. Please look closer.

Comment: Because `x` can appear in the basename too, so you don't want to replace `x` with `.` in `s`. You have to do it only for the values of each token.